# How to include opencv native library while exporting to jar

Tags: java, android, opencv, jar

I am preparing jar that compares the images and returns results accordingly.
I am using OpenCV for comparing the same. When i exported the jar and provided to my collegue to consume it in android application, he is getting error on the following line.

```
System.loadLibrary(CORE.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

On checking, i found that the library is being consumed form the local path on my system. How can i pass the following library in the JAR, so that every once can consume it.

Also i am not sure, whether it would work even then, as System.loadLibrary tries to consume from the JAVA paths in the system.
Any alternative to load this library from classpath?

Open for suggestions.

Comment: You've tagged android, do you mean apk?

Comment: @NabinBhandari, I will be importing the JAR in android app, so thought to  tagged android as there may be some alternative for what i am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native libraries depend on libraries outside of the JVM, and can not be added in a portable way to a Java application. That being said: You can still include the file in the jar by simply opening the jar file, which is a zip, add the file in, and reference is by path (ex: `/yourlibs/bla.lib`

Loading from a jar would then be:

```
   NativeUtils.loadLibraryFromJar("/yourlibs/bla.lib");
```

You might miss a lot of dependencies and will have all of those manually by reading docs, scanning code and testing your code, and then it might still be limited to certain OS installations.